# Splitting image data set: Training, Validation & Test

Tags: r, validation

I have some code R code where I split image data into a training and validation set for a machine learning classification problem. That worked just fine, but now I need to add a final test set. Now I'm getting an error but not sure what is wrong.

Here is the code that I tried and worked:

```
image_subset <-
    cbind(file_paths = image_names_subset$file_paths, y_subset) %>%
    mutate(file_paths = as.character(file_paths))

  y_cols <- colnames(y_subset)

  subset_output_classes <- y_cols

  train_val_split <- 0.70

  train_image_rows <-
    sort(sample(nrow(image_subset), train_val_split * nrow(image_subset)))

  val_image_rows <-
    which(!(seq(1, nrow(image_subset)) %in% train_image_rows))

  image_subset_train <-
    image_subset[train_image_rows, ]

  image_subset_val <-
    image_subset[-train_image_rows, ]
```

```
 image_subset <-
    cbind(file_paths = image_names_subset$file_paths, y_subset) %>%
    mutate(file_paths = as.character(file_paths))

  y_cols <- colnames(y_subset)

  subset_output_classes <- y_cols

  train_val_split <- 0.60


#Added, want to be able to split the remaining 40% of data in 1/2 for validation and test sets 

val_test_split <- 0.50 

  train_image_rows <-
    sort(sample(nrow(image_subset), train_val_split * nrow(image_subset)))

# Added
  val_image_rows <-
    which(!(seq(1, nrow(image_subset)) %in% train_image_rows))

# Error occurs here when I run this command
  test_image_rows <- sample(nrow(val_image_rows), val_test_split * nrow(val_image_rows))

  val_image_rows2 <- which(!(seq(1, nrow(val_image_rows)) %in% test_image_rows))
```

- Expected 60% of the rows from image_subset to populate train_image_rows. This worked
- I expected the remaining 40% of the rows to populate val_image_rows. This also worked
- I get an error when trying split out a test set to populate test_image_rows:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
invalid 'size' argument
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem:
- val-image_rows is a vector of row numbers, not a data frame like image_subset
- use the following code:

```
 train_image_rows <-
    sort(sample(nrow(image_subset), train_val_split * nrow(image_subset)))

# All rows for validation and test
val_image_rows <-
    which(!(seq(1, nrow(image_subset)) %in% train_image_rows))

# Validation set rows only
val_image_rows2 <- sample(val_image_rows, val_test_split * length(val_image_rows))

# Test set rows only
test_image_rows <- val_image_rows[which(!(val_image_rows %in% val_image_rows2))]
```